# Main container background color not Covering child section area

Tags: html, css

I want main container color should cover child element also. I can't give 100vh or fixed height.

Please see image for details.

[image: Expected result]

[Code Link](https://codepen.io/pawankotak/pen/YxXoMB)

```html
<div class="container">   
 <input class="nav" type="radio" name="nav" checked=true/> 
 <div class="nav">CategoryA</div>   
 <input class="nav" type="radio" name="nav" /> 
 <div class="nav">CategoryB</div>   
 <input class="nav" type="radio" name="nav" /> 
 <div class="nav">CategoryC</div> 
 <input class="nav" type="radio" name="nav" /> 
 <div class="nav">CategoryD</div> 
 <div class="main clearfix">   
  <section>
   <h1>Category A</h1>
   <main>
    <label class="heading" for="checkbox_1A">HEADING A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1A" style="display:none;">
    <div id="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus turpis ac posuere laoreet. Donec vehicula hendrerit nibh, in laoreet nibh rutrum a. Aenean vestibulum lectus sem.</div>
   </main>
   <main>
    <label class="heading" for="checkbox_1B">HEADING B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1B" style="display:none;">
    <div id="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</div>
   </main>
  </section>     
  <section>
   <h1>Category B</h1>
   <main>
    <label class="heading" for="checkbox_2B">HEADING B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2B" style="display:none;">
    <div id="hidden">Praesent non nulla id tortor malesuada tincidunt</div>
   </main>
  </section>     
  <section>
   <h1>Category C</h1>
  </section>     
  <section>
   <h1>Category D</h1>
  </section> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Johannes both html and css are available on https://codepen.io/pawankotak/pen/YxXoMB

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that everything inside the main section is positioned absolute, so basically the browser sees the main content as empty.

So either you position the sections inside the main content in other ways (not using absolute position), or you give .main a height of 100vh:

```
.main {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: 100vh;
}
```